# How to change the src attr in <audio> tag with another online mp3 resource and reload it

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, audio

I tried to modify the src attribute of the  tag and reload it. However, this seems not work.

```
     $.getJSON('/handler', function(data) {
        var items=[]
        alert('data')
        $('#artist').html(data.artist);
        $('#title').html(data.title);
        $(".audio").attr('src', data.url);
        $(".audio").attr('autoplay', true);
        $(".audio").load();
    }



        <audio id="players" class="audio" controls>
        <!-- <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg"> -->
        <source  src="http://mr4.douban.com/201307252205/c015e7928c2cbcb3be6ad0e38ff21838/view/song/small/p1451474.mp3" type="audio/mp3" reload="auto" >
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
```

I did some experiments, if change the src with some local files like:

```
 $(".audio").attr('src','/static/music/p186609.mp3')
```

This works, however if I use

```
 $(".audio").attr('src','http://mr4.douban.com/201307252205/c015e7928c2cbcb3be6ad0e38ff21838/view/song/small/p1451474.mp3')
```

This does not work.

Comment: Just taking a stab, but you might need to check out jsonp.

Comment: you're trying to directly change the src tag of the audio element, I think you want to change the src tag of the source element inside the audio element

Comment: @Charles380 not work as well. Later I tried other mp3 links, they all work. Problem is the link, quite strange, can use wget to get the mp3 file, while cannot get it by changing src.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to browser policy to prevent cross-site scripting.